# Method seekToMillis() does not work properly when video not loading

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using **Youtube Player API** as a player and I'm trying to use seekToMillis method to skip to the end of video. My problem is when video not fully loading and I apply seekToMillis by the number of total video's duration, a seekbar just move to the end of possible loading not the end of the video. For example, if the video is 3 minutes and it has load around 1:50 minutes. So when I apply seekToMillis, a seekbar will move to video at 1:50 minutes not 3. I want it move to the end of video.

How can I solve this problem? or can I just force a player to end the video in other way?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my language.

Comment: You might want to double check your implementation on `onSeekTo`. Try and follow this tutorial - [Using the YouTube API to Embed Video in an Android App](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/), it shows how to load and play YouTube videos and to customize and control the video playback experience. Also check if you are passing the correct format of `seekToMillis()` which should be in sec time. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I will try your solution and I'll share my progress if it is work or not. Thank you :)